making a data frame reactive to SelectInput()
I have two data frames df and df2. As per code  below df2 should contain data from df when filtered by dateRangeInput(). However, df2 is not reacting to a selected date range when new rows added to df. What am I missing in the code below?
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(lubridate)
library(rhandsontable)

df <- data.table(
  dasa = as.character(c("01/05/2024", "04/06/2024")),
  nasa = as.numeric(2,3),
  casa = as.character(c("abc", "def")),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

cc <- strsplit(df$dasa,"/",fixed=TRUE)
d <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(df$dasa))-2]
m <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(df$dasa))-1]
y <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(df$dasa))]
df$das <- paste0(y,"-",m,"-",d)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Financial Statements"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    menuItem("Home", tabName = "home"),
    menuItem("Accounting", tabName = "Recognition",
             menuSubItem("item1", tabName = "Item1")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
       tabItem(
        tabName = "Item1",
        fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 6,
            "Trial1_col1",
            rHandsontableOutput("Trial1_Item1")
          ),
          column(
            width = 6,
            "Trial1_col2",
            selectInput("choices", "Choose an option:",
                        choices = c("choice 1", "choice 2")),
            uiOutput("nested_ui")
          ),
          column(
            width = 6,
            "Trial1_col3",
            rHandsontableOutput("Trial1_Item2")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    data$df <- as.data.frame(df)
  })

  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$Trial1_Item1))
      data$df <- hot_to_r(input$Trial1_Item1)
  })

  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$Trial1_Item2))
      data$df2 <- hot_to_r(input$Trial1_Item2)
  })

  observe({

    if (!is.null(input$dates)) {
      selected_dates <- seq(as.Date(input$dates[1]),
                            as.Date(input$dates[2]), by = "day")
      data$df2 <- df[as.Date(df$das) %in% selected_dates, ]
    } else {
      selected_dates2 <- unique(df$dasa)
      data$df2 <- df[df$dasa %in% selected_dates2, ]
    }
  })

  output$Trial1_Item1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$df[,c(1:3)], stretchH = "all", rowHeaderWidth = 50, height = 300) |>
      hot_col(1, format = "%d.%m.%Y", type = "date")
  })

  output$nested_ui <- renderUI({
    if (input$choices == "choice 1") {
      dateRangeInput("dates", "Select a date range:", format = "dd/mm/yyyy",
                     start = "2024-01-01", end = Sys.Date())
    } else if (input$choices == "choice 2") {
      textInput("text", "Enter some text:")
    }
  })

  output$Trial1_Item2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$df2[,c(1:3)], stretchH = "all", rowHeaderWidth = 50, height = 300) |>
      hot_col(1, format = "%d.%m.%Y", type = "date")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


You df has zero records here.  How are you expecting to subset it to get df2?

It works fine for me if df is non-null and you pick the correct dates.

I can't put in df any predifined records. Users are expected to create their own data. Therefore, df is kept empty. Following the advice of YBS above, I have created new rows in df as a user, but the issue is still not resolved.

I also tried by putting in df some rows with predefined sample records which I changed thereafter. df2 is giving only predefined data of df and is not getting updated once data in df is changed. Besides, df2 is not showing rows of df which were not intially inserted, but created newly.

You are not showing how the user is creating new records in this MRE. Perhaps the date format in the input is the issue.  Also, you need to define how your app should react when there are zero records (initially).

dear YBS, I have updated my code above. As per your remark I have added two sample rows to df. One can play around with dateRangeInput() to filter out/in existing rows. By right-clicking the mouse one can add new rows to df and try to change date range in dateRangeInput() to embrace these new rows. Yet, df2 does not react to filter in these newly created rows of df. Also there is one more problem: When dates of the initially existing two rows of df are changed, df2 does not get updated accordingly. Hence, I definitely should be missing or doing wrong something in my code.

You need to use the updated data frame data$df to update data$df2.  Try this
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(lubridate)
library(rhandsontable)

df <- data.table(
  dasa = as.character(c("01/05/2024", "04/06/2024")),
  nasa = as.numeric(2,3),
  casa = as.character(c("abc", "def")),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

cc <- strsplit(df$dasa,"/",fixed=TRUE)
d <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(df$dasa))-2]
m <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(df$dasa))-1]
y <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(df$dasa))]
df$das <- paste0(y,"-",m,"-",d)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Financial Statements"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    menuItem("Home", tabName = "home"),
    menuItem("Accounting", tabName = "Recognition",
             menuSubItem("item1", tabName = "Item1")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Item1",
        fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 6,
            "Trial1_col1",
            rHandsontableOutput("Trial1_Item1")
          ),
          column(
            width = 6,
            "Trial1_col2",
            selectInput("choices", "Choose an option:",
                        choices = c("choice 1", "choice 2")),
            uiOutput("nested_ui")
          ),
          column(
            width = 6,
            "Trial1_col3",
            rHandsontableOutput("Trial1_Item2")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    data$df <- as.data.frame(df)
  })
  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$Trial1_Item1)) {
      dfa <- hot_to_r(input$Trial1_Item1)
      cc <- strsplit(dfa$dasa,"/",fixed=TRUE)
      d <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(dfa$dasa))-2]
      m <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(dfa$dasa))-1]
      y <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(dfa$dasa))]
      dfa$das <- paste0(y,"-",m,"-",d)
      data$df <- dfa
      # print(data$df)
      if (!is.null(input$dates)) {
        # print(input$dates[2])
        df1 <- data$df
        selected_dates <- seq(as.Date(input$dates[1]),
                              as.Date(input$dates[2]), by = "day")
        data$df2 <- df1[as.Date(df1$das) %in% selected_dates, ]
      } else {
        selected_dates2 <- unique(dfa$dasa)
        data$df2 <- dfa[dfa$dasa %in% selected_dates2, ]
      }
      # print(data$df2)
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$Trial1_Item2))
      data$df2 <- hot_to_r(input$Trial1_Item2)
  })
  
  output$Trial1_Item1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$df[,c(1:3)], stretchH = "all", rowHeaderWidth = 50, height = 300) |>
      hot_col(1, format = "%d/%m/%Y", type = "date")
  })
  
  output$nested_ui <- renderUI({
    if (input$choices == "choice 1") {
      dateRangeInput("dates", "Select a date range:", format = "dd/mm/yyyy",
                     start = "2000-01-01", end = Sys.Date())
    } else if (input$choices == "choice 2") {
      textInput("text", "Enter some text:")
    }
  })
  
  output$Trial1_Item2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$df2[,c(1:3)], stretchH = "all", rowHeaderWidth = 50, height = 300) |>
      hot_col(1, format = "%d/%m/%Y", type = "date")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


dear YBS, your solution is perfect. Thank You for your time and efforts! Well done!
